# How to pass build artifacts from gitlab stages that use different docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hi have Gitlab pipeline with multiple stages. I want to build a React project in a Nodejs container and then create another docker container with nginx on it for deployment on AWS.

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image:
  name: node:14-alpine

cache:
  key: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG'
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - .yarn

stages:
  - install
  - build
  - deploy

job_install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - echo 'yarn-offline-mirror ".yarn-cache/"' >> .yarnrc
    - echo 'yarn-offline-mirror-pruning true' >> .yarnrc
    - yarn install
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - yarn.lock
    paths:
      - .yarn-cache/
  tags:
    - docker

job_build:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG'
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - .yarn
  script:
    - yarn build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build
  tags:
    - docker

job_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker
  services: 
    - docker:dind
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk upgrade
    - apk add bash
    - chmod +x ./build-scripts/build_wrapper.sh
    - ./build-scripts/build_wrapper.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - BUILDTAG.txt
      - env.sh
      - logs
    when: always
  resource_group: realizeui_deployment
  tags:
    - docker
```

Basically build_wrapper.sh file will exec `docker build .` for a Dockerfile in the code repo.This Dockerfile will install nginx and other tools in it.

I want to pass artifacts: /build from stage:build to stage:deploy for using in nginx container.

I have tried finding solution in documentation with no luck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

So I found the solution. I just needed to add previous job as dependency in deploy. This makes gitlab download all the artifacts from the dependency job and make them available for deploy job.

Here is how the deploy job looks like:

```
job_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker
  services: 
    - docker:dind
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  dependencies: 
    - job_build
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk upgrade
    - apk add bash
    - chmod +x ./build-scripts/build_wrapper.sh
    - ./build-scripts/build_wrapper.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - BUILDTAG.txt
      - env.sh
      - logs
    when: always
  resource_group: realizeui_deployment
  tags:
    - docker
```